# Как записать вот такую схему на jquery?

Tags: jquery

То есть
Когда в диве с `.class1` имеется класс `active`

```
<a href='#' class='class1 active' onclick="return true;">///</a> 
<a href='#' class='class1' onclick="return false;">///</a>
<a href='#' class='class1' onclick="return false;">///</a>
```

То ему нужно изменить атрибут (`onclick="return false;"` на `onclick="return true;"`), а когда класса `active` нету, то атрибут возвращается тот что бы изначально `onclick="return false;"`.
У меня три блока, и класс `active` может добавляться как при клике на блок, так и автоматически при автопрокрутке блоков (как слайдер).
Вот как мне записать такую схему, просто ток изучаю jquery и очень сложно!!!!!

Comment: `$(".class1").click(function(){ return $(this).hasClass('active'); })` как-то так, видимо?

Comment: или `$("a.class1").click(function(e){ if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) e.preventDefault();})`

Comment: Мне нужно как-то сделать, чтобы менялся атрибут onclick="return false;" на onclick="return true;" когда в этом блоке есть класс active. А класс active у меня добавляется как при клике на блок так и при автопромотке (как в слайдере)

Comment: уберите вообще свой атрибут. не делается так последние лет 10. если вам надо запретить переход по ссылке с классом active, то вообще можно решить это, отключив pointer-events в css.

Answer (score 1):

В DOM видно как меняется `onclick=""`.

```js
function PropOnclick () {
  $('.class1').each(function(){ // Пробегаем по всем элементам с классом .class1
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) // если у элемента есть класс active
      $(this).attr('onclick', 'true'); // то ставим ему onclick true
    else // если нет
      $(this).attr('onclick', 'false'); // то onclick false
  });
} PropOnclick(); // выполним скрипт при загрузки страницы

$('.class1').on('click', function(){
  // это для примера
  $('.class1.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  // это для примера

  // После того как сменится класс active
  PropOnclick(); // выполняем функцию ещё раз
});
```

```css
.class1[onclick="true"] {
  color: red;
}

.class1[onclick="false"] {
  color: #333;
}

.class1.active {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='class1 active'>///</a> 
<a href='#' class='class1'>///</a>
<a href='#' class='class1'>///</a>
```

Comment: вы понимаете, что `return false;` (а не просто `false`  как у вас) в `onclick` предназначен для того, чтобы просто остановить стандартное действие клика на ссылку и перехода по ней?

Comment: @teran, ох, точно, что-то я не подумал об этом.. Сейчас исправлю